# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'id' was corrupted

Tags: c++, runtime

I get `"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'id' was corrupted."` on `while condition` . I've no idea! what causes this err?

```
void Term::set_id()
{
    char id[Term::ID_LENGTH];
    do
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter the term id(like 90911): ";
        cin >> id;
    }while(valid_id(id) != true);
}

bool Term::valid_id(char *id)
{
    //counting how many chars id has got:
    int n=0;
    for(char* str=id; *(str+n)!=0; n++);

    if(n!=Term::ID_LENGTH)
        return false;

    //checking that id consist of digits only
    int i=0;
    for( char* str=id; (*(str+i)>=48 && *(str+i)<=57) && i<Term::ID_LENGTH; i++);
    if(i<Term::ID_LENGTH)
        return false;

    int fy= (*(id) - 48) * 10 + (*(id+1) - 48);//former year
    int ly= (*(id+2) - 48) * 10 + (*(id+3) - 48);//latter year
    int t= *(id+4) - 48;//term number
    if(ly - fy != 1)//any difference other than 1
        return false;
    if(!(t==1 || t==2 || t==0))//t==0 is for summer term
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Out-of-bounds array access, somewhere. Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: You need to look into proper string function (e.g. `std::strlen()`) and character classification functions (e.g. `std::isdigit()`).

Answer (score 2):

This code looks like a simple array overrun. `std::cin >> str` for `str` being a `char` array or a pointer to `char` is the C++ version of C's `gets()` if you don't set up the stream's `width()` to limit the number of characters to be read:

```
char id[Term::ID_LENGTH];
std::cin.width(Term::ID_LENGTH); // <-- without this you are prone to array overrun!
if (std::cin >> id) {
    // deal with a successful read
}
```

You should consider using `std::string` for the input of character strings:

```
std::string id;
if (std::cin >> id) {
    // deal with a successful read
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was `Term::ID_LENGTH` forgotten to count the '\0'.